# custom titlebar button in tabactivity android

Tags: android, button, custom-titlebar

Heey. How to add button in custom title bar through TabActivity ? I can set title TextView depending on which subactivity is called. But i cant figure out how to add button ?

My TabActivity:

```
public class TabsManager extends TabActivity {

static TabsManager mTab;

@Override
protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mTab = this;
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabhostbottom);
    }
public void setMyTitle(String string) {

    ((Activity) mTab).getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);
    textView.setText(string);       
}
```

And my subactivity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    TabsManager.mTab.setMyTitle("Activity1");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_club);         
    TabsManager.mTab.setMyTitle("Activity1");
     }
```